# Android - Multiple GridViews in a ListView

Tags: android, gridview, calendar

I know that there are questions similar to this but I found no solution from it.
What I'm trying to do is create a list of `GridViews`. 
Something like this:

[image]

What I currently have is this:
`item_cell.xml` <-- layout for each item in the grid
`layout_grid.xml` <-- layout of the grid
`list_view.xml` <-- layout of the list which is then included to the layout of my `Activity`.

So what i was thinking was to inflate the `item_cell` to `layout_grid.xml` then inflate that after to `list_view`. Is this kind of idea possible? I havent tried it though because I'm not sure of how to approach it.

One thing, is there any library that could help this kind of approach?

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

---

As an additional question, my GridView is like a calendar but the days of the calendar are on the first column and the rest of the columns are somewhat like a schedule.

```
                  A        B       C      D
        Mon     data1    data2   data3
        Tues    data1    data2
        Wed     data1    data2
        Thurs
        Fri
        Sat
        Sun
        Mon
        .
        .
        .
```

Is there other way to implement this instead of putting it in an Array/List and calculate in which cell data should be added by just using an info from `row` and `columns`?

To illustrate:
     {Mon, data1, data2, data3, Tues, data1, data2, Wed. . . . . }

Again, i need englightenment. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, I think you're thinking of something like this: https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/grid-in-a-listview/

For the second question, could you elaborate at all? Do the column headers for data elements need to be displayed?

Comment: For the column headers, there are just static and yes the will be displayed but i created a separate layout for that on top of the gridView.