# Android - Implementing a calendar-like gridview with days in the first column

Tags: android, gridview, calendar

This question is actually related to this  [question#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567211/android-multiple-gridviews-in-a-listview/31570460#31570460) of mine.

I want to create a calendar with it's day on the first column. 
My other plan on implementing this one was using GridView. Then to get the values of days and month, is to use `java.util.Calendar`.

This is my current progress but i dont know how to proceed because I was also thinking what happens if it will fall on December - January of next year.

```
        String dailyTask[][][] = new String[MONTHS][DAYS][DATA_PER_DAY_OF_MONTH];
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        List<String> taskItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 
        int thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int startDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) -1;

        String lastDay = getLastDay();
        String[] splitDate = lastDay.split("-");
        int latestYear = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]);
        int latestMonth = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]);
        int latestDay = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]);

        if(thisMonth < latestMonth){
            for(int x = thisMonth; x <= latestMonth; x++){
                for(int y = thisDay; y <= getMaxDaysofMonth(x); y++){
                    dailyTask[x][y][0] = " "; 
                }
            }
        }
```

To illustrate the grid, this is how it will look like.

[image]

The `0`s are any data.

Any library suggestion will help. Or if there is a better way to implement this kind of calendar or whatever this is called. 
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check `AnCal`[https://code.google.com/p/ancal/] and others http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Development/calendar/index.htm

Comment: I was able to check out AnCal but there was an error in one class `dayStyle` in which i was not able to resolve. I will check others that you suggested.